# Parent business unit deletion

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit

We have a parent business unit.
We are creating a child business unit.
Both BU's synch to their respective SF CRM instance(s). Multi org is enabled.

Both BU's will have their own assets and wont share contacts between each other.

In the future the parent BU will be disconnected from its CRM connection and eventually deleted.

In that scenario, what would happen to the child BU. Does it become the parent BU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not let you delete it if it has any child BUs or active users and child BUs don’t become parent automatically.

You will need to move all child BUs to a different parent and make sure no users are assigned and only then you will be able to delete the „old” parent BU.